# Resizing contents in TabNavigator in flex3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe

Hi I am working on tabNavigator in flex 3.
I have tileList within it. Contents in the tab comes dynamically so I cannot provide explicitly fixed height and width.
I need to resize the tabs depending on the contents within it. 
To resize the tabs I have enabled 'resizeToContent' property of tabNavigator.For some reason it is not resizing as expected.

Could anybody please suggest me the way out of it. 
Thanks

---

Hey thanks Gregor for you reply,

'resizeToContent' works fine for other child items in tabNavigator but fails when I use tileList as child in tabNavigator that time tileList resizes to its default size(4 rows are only visible). So i was wondering if there any way so that I can force tileList to display all its items without putting scrollbars after its default size.

just by invalidating size on creationComplete ,will that resize all tabs for me. I am having n-number of tabs in tabNavigator as user can add tabs and content within it.
Could you please explain me, how can I achieve this.
I am new to flex so just getting confused with its behaviorand struggling with this issue from long time.

Answer (score 0):

resizeToContent only works when the user changes tabs. If you want the tab to resize once the content has been added, you need to listen for the appropriate event (creationComplete probably) and invalidate the size of the TabNavigator. That will give it an opportunity to resize itself.